# kubectl ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec;

Tags: kubectl, minikube

When I try to run `kubectl apply -f 02-php-apache-deployment.yaml` I get the following error:

`error: error validating "02-php-apache-deployment.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

This is my Deployment yml file:

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: php-apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-apache
        image: k8s.gcr.io/hpa-example
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "password"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

I'm using minikube version v1.6.2

and kubectl version:

```js
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.8", GitCommit:"211047e9a1922595eaa3a1127ed365e9299a6c23", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T12:11:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok I found it I was missing the selector matchLabels and app inside it.

I changed this piece:

```js
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-apache
```

And final correct yml file:

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-apache
        image: k8s.gcr.io/hpa-example
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "password"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```